# simulation of endogenous skewed regressor

Tags: regression, stata, simulation, skewness, endogeneity

I have a question regarding endogeneity. I have to simulate a variable that is skewed and at the same time correlated with the error term, whereas the error term, as well as two other exogenous variable should be normal distributed.

I already tried:

```
drawnorm r1 r2 e, corr(1,.5,.5 | .5,1,5 |.5,.5,1) n(1000)
gen x1 = rpoisson(5) // in order to get the skewed variable
gen x = x1 + r1      // to get the correlation in the skewed data
```

but in fact, this did not work. `x` is skewed but not correlated with `e`.

Comment: One more thing, this should be implemented in stata :)

Comment: I don't read Stata well, but it looks like you defined `e` as a variable that is independent of everything else in the 1st line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the correlation matrix before. The way you wrote down the `drawnorm` command Stata will return an error (also because you specified an asymmetric correlation matrix, though I assume that 5 in row 2, column 3 was supposed to be .5).

If you run

```
// set a seed for replicability
set seed 777 

// specify and list the correlation matrix
mat C = (1,.5,.5 \ .5,1,.5 \.5,.5,1)
mat list C

C[3,3]
    c1  c2  c3
r1   1  .5  .5
r2  .5   1   5
r3  .5  .5   1

// simulate the data, generate x and display the correlations
drawnorm r1 r2 e, corr(C) n(10000)
gen x1 = rpoisson(5)
gen x = x1 + r1
corr
             |       r1       r2        e       x1        x
-------------+---------------------------------------------
          r1 |   1.0000
          r2 |   0.4947   1.0000
           e |   0.5002   0.5009   1.0000
          x1 |  -0.0142  -0.0168   0.0019   1.0000
           x |   0.3932   0.1855   0.2050   0.9138   1.0000
```

However, your `x` is not going to be very skewed or maybe not as much as you desired.

```
sum x, det
                              x
-------------------------------------------------------------
      Percentiles      Smallest
 1%     .0051123      -2.543394
 5%     1.213776      -1.960374
10%     1.952922      -1.898967       Obs               10000
25%     3.262814      -1.856982       Sum of Wgt.       10000

50%     4.857108                      Mean            5.00197
                        Largest       Std. Dev.      2.438195
75%     6.617982       14.76838
90%     8.203129       15.10846       Variance       5.944795
95%     9.160346       15.78603       Skewness       .2930976
99%     11.13091        16.5633       Kurtosis       3.034108
```

You can also control the mean and standard deviation of `r1` and `r2` in the `drawnorm` command by specifying the vectors

```
matrix m = (3,5)
matrix stdevs = (0.4,1)
```

and use them in the options of the command as

```
drawnorm r1 r2 e, corr(C) n(10000) means(m) sds(stdevs)
```